# Magento: How to get random category on home page?

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to display a random category on home page that changes after every few hours?

Comment: in homepage page means navigation or in content?

Comment: I mean in content of home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create a new record to put in database both a reference to the category id and the start hour it has been displayed. Then put in code: if start hour is longer from now more than a few hours, get all categories id and randomly pick one. Update the database, then show the category.
This could be a good starting point to do some search and develop your work.

Comment: Will it have any heavy effect on execution time? Or is there a more optimized way?

Comment: It will, but not that much: the most of the code is inside the if, and will occur only once a few hour. You can put this code in a cronjob to increase performance if you think it could be better.